# How to carry a concealed firearm on a bike?

Tags: clothes, cargo, us

For those of you that happen to cycle through rough neighborhoods and are able to do concealed carry of firearms...  Wondering what you wear to conceal them that works well while cycling.  Obviously the standard cycling outfit isn't going to do any good whatsoever...  Various back/fanny packs seem like they'd be inconvenient.  Most jackets that would work fine while walking would tend to "ride up" I'd think.  Just curious as to what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Let's assume all permits are in order, and so on, and that this is a legal situation, and answer this question seriously. I think it's fascinating.

Comment: I guess it could be extended to open carry as well.  In my particular State of the Union, open carry is legal without a permit, unless in a motor vehicle (and bicycle does not fall within the ORV's definition of "motor vehicle", so it's like walking/riding a horse in that regards).

Comment: Is your intention to stop and then shoot? Or are you also looking for firing ranges that allow bicycles?

Comment: Just the simple act of carrying while riding was all I had in mind.  Preferably in a way that keeps it totally concealed.  At one of the places I work, people with permits are encouraged to carry.

Comment: Not possible for pistols/handguns here in New Zealand - they're highly controlled and permits are rare.  Shotgun or a 22 on the farm would be possible, but very few farmers ride bicycles, they tend to prefer a quad-motorbike.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like stuff made for joggers could work for cycling.

- http://www.activeprogear.com/jogger_holster.html

Would a small triangle frame bag work?  The kind I'm thinking of seem about the right size to hold a small-to-medium pistol, and fit on the rear end of the top tube.  Some sit on top, secured by the seat post, some hang under, secured by the seat tube.  Lots of options...

- http://www.google.com/images?q=triangle+frame+bag

Or a frame bag designed to attach to the front of the top tube.  Or a handlebar bag...

Comment: Similar to the first link you can also get messenger bag.  http://www.blackhawk.com/product/Covert-Carry-Messenger-Bag,1185,1394.htm

Answer (score 29):

A thread on this subject on Bikeforums ran to pages and pages...   Some expressing utter horror that a bicyclist would feel the need to be armed, others ridiculing the whole idea, others with decent suggestions.
I'm a cop, I know that numbers of cyclists ride in conditions that are less than optimal.
We have had armed robberies and muggings of cyclists here in St. Louis, usually the bad guy is after the high-end bike.
As well, mountain bikers have been attacked by cougars in Western states.  Bicycling magazine detailed several such incidents while I subscribed.   Rare, but possible.

First up.  Having the weapon concealed on the bike is rather a bad idea if the intent of the bad guy is to steal the bike...  Your first indication of anything wrong might simply be a pedestrian knocking you over at an intersection.  Now, he's got your pistol too...

Unfortunately, cycling gear isn't much designed for concealed-carry.  I have a little Taurus 2" 38 special as an "off-duty" weapon.  Drops right into my jersey pocket.
Sure, it "prints" there.  But then, I'm a cop...I don't care.
A reasonable idea is the "fanny pack" (I've just been informed that Aussies call them "bum bags"...).
As far as I know, [you can still buy](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENUS285&q=fanny+pack+for+concealed+weapon&aq=1v&aqi=g1g-v1g-j3g-m1&aql=&oq=fanny+pack+for+conc) a fanny pack that is designed specifically to carry a firearm....

Comment: My shoulder holster rides quite nicely under a vest.  During weather too warm for a vest, I find a small (300 cubic inches) backpack easily conceals both a compact 9mm with holster and a kydex dual mag holster.  I agree that storing a firearm on the bike is not ideal.

Answer (score 5):

I have a [Bike Nashbar frame pack](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_167563_-1_201497_10000_200352) that would definitely fit a compact frame handgun:
[image]

Comment: Any idea whether there are triangular bags that you could use as regular bags?

Comment: I have one of these but it bulged and rubbed my legs.  So I added a velcro strap at the bottom, and hung it in the forepeak of the main frame triangle.  Works great further ahead, and can be accessed while riding.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran across a line of holsters that look interesting.  Relatively low cost, so I may have to try one out to see how well it works.  http://www.pistolwear.com/

Comment: Arrived really fast. Seems to be good quality. Works as advertised. Even now that I'm carrying some extra weight and with a rather large Beretta/Stoeger 8000, it does the job with an appropriate clothing choice (can't be see through, needs to be a little bit baggy, etc.).  Only downside is that it's soft, therefore you don't have positive prevention of accidental trigger activation. They recommend that if you don't have a safety (I'll add "one that won't accidentally be turned off, and one that's not prone to failure like some very early SAs") that you carry with an empty chamber for safety.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to get a full size 1911 into one of those (and I do manage to conceal such a beast).

Answer (score 3):

I have one like the Nashbar frame pack, different brand but substantively the same thing. Sucks that my Kahr PM-9, small though it is, adds pounds to my ultra-light bike, but in certain areas, I'd much rather not leave my firearm at home.

Answer (score 3):

One option that works well for me is using a belly band holster and a Ruger Lcp. It hides easily under my cycling jerseys and is comfortable and secure even on 70+ mile rides in the heat of summer. The only real issue is that the sweat can corrode the non stainless slide and spare magazine. If you can spring for it get your slide and magazine covered at Robar in their NP3. If not be sure to clean and re oil your gun after every ride.

Comment: Sweat would be a problem on any vigorous activity, not just riding.  What is "robar in their NP3" ?

Answer (score 2):

First off you'll have to wear mostly regular clothes.

Using an inside-the-waistband holster will suit you well. You can tuck a shirt in over the holster, then if you wear a jacket over that, it will be completely hidden.

I have [an MTAC holster](http://www.comp-tac.com/product_info.php?products_id=95), and I sometimes carry when I am buying or selling stuff from craigslist. I've never had issues where it became visible that I was carrying.

Answer (score 1):

I use an Assault III backpack with a waist strap and a drop leg holster modified to attach to my hip using the leg platform as a pad. I have a Glock 29 and it works well on a mountain bike.

Answer (score 1):

I pedaled my bicycle from Seattle to key west carrying two guns .  I used two safepacker holsters strapped through the waist band for a Fannie pack which was attached around my waist.  Just Google safepacker holsters to get to the sites .  On the early portion of the trip I carried a 44 magnum Alaskan redhawk, then switched it out with a glock 20 and ruger 380 incase my primary malfunctioned .I switched the 44 magnum to the glock 20 after I was out of the mountains. 
My every day carry on my bicycle around Miami beach is a glock 29 and a ruger 380 still using two safe packer holsters.glock29's are serious firepower as is the glock 20 and 44magnum Alaskan red hawk.

The 44 magnum will will take care of all natural threats I am told while the glock 20 has a tad less firepower.

Answer (score 0):

I carry either a Sig938 (9mm) or a S&W 640 Revolver (357 Mag) in a TommyGun fanny pack works like a charm