# Dealing with cars harassing cyclists in the US

Tags: safety, legal

Tonight as my partner was out riding a car swerved over to the fog line as it passed and laid on the horn before speeding off. While most of the driver around here are extremely courteous something like this happens to one or the other of us several times a year. For the most part we're just thankful that the car only came close and annoyed by the powerless feeling in response to what seems like harassment. Usually the car is gone before we can get a plate or other good identifying information.

So, the question, is there anything worth doing in response to incidents like this? I'm wondering about things like:

- Reporting to police
- Using a helmet camera or something like one in hopes of capturing the plate
- Letters to the editor of local papers

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25451/how-to-get-over-anger-at-inconsiderate-drivers/25452#25452

Comment: Its not much different from what @andy256 linked -- in almost all of the US, there's pretty much nothing you can do.

Comment: I hear Canada is nicer to cyclists....